# Как на практике работает MultiLevel Security?

Tags: linux, безопасность, selinux

В SELinux есть такой механизм доступа, как MultiLevel Security. Согласно описанию, это работает так: "no write down, no read up". Однако не совсем понятно, как это работает *на деле*. Как бы, SELinux берет под свой контроль вообще всю систему, а в ней есть не только обычные файлы и директории. Я представляю, как подобное может работать с файлами, директориями, сокетами, трубами (pipe). Но как это правило работает, например, с процессами, самим ядром или ещё чем-либо? Не говоря уже о том, что даже с тем же файлом возможны операции не только чтения/записи. Как *на практике* работает MLS?

Даже приведу что-то типа задачи в качестве уточнения своего вопроса:

> У нас есть 3 файла: `/opt/confidential_exec`, `/opt/secret_exec`, `/opt/topsecret_exec`. Эти файлы имеют следующие права доступа: владелец **root**, группа **root**, права владельца: *чтение, запись и исполнение*, права членов группы **root**: никакие, права других: никакие. Запущен процесс *bash* с контекстом `u:r:bash_exec:s0:c0`. Файлы `/opt/confidential_exec`, `/opt/secret_exec` и `/opt/topsecret_exec` имеют соответственно контексты `u:r:secret_exec:s0:c0`, `u:r:secret_exec:s1:c0`, `u:r:secret_exec:s2:c0`. Имеем также следующие SELinux правила в формате .te:

```
allow bash_exec secret_exec:file { getattr relabelto unlink ioctl execute append read setattr swapon write lock create rename mounton quotaon relabelfrom link }

allow bash_exec secret_exec:process { sigchld sigkill sigstop signull signal ptrace getsched setsched getsession getpgid setpgid getcap setcap getattr setrlimit }

neverallow bash_exec secret_exec:process transition
```

> Что процесс с контекстом *bash_exec* сможет сделать с каждым из трех исполняемых файлов в `/opt` и с каждым процессом данных файлов, если он сможет их запустить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Политика многоуровневой безопасности (MLS), применяемая SELinux, ограничивает действия процесс с контекстом **bash_exec** может выполнять над исполняемыми файлами в **/opt** и над процессами, связанными с этими файлами:

**allow bash_exec secret_exec:file { ... }**: это правило предоставляет контексту процесса **bash_exec** различные связанные с файлами разрешения при взаимодействии с файлами, помеченными как **secret_exec**.

Эти разрешения включают

- **getattr** (получение атрибутов файла),
- **relabelto** (изменение метки безопасности файла на более высокий уровень),
- **unlink** (удаление файла),
- **ioctl** (выполнение операций управления вводом/выводом над файлом),
- **append** (запись данных в конец файла),
- **read** (чтение данных из файла),
- **setattr** (установка атрибутов файла),
- **swapon** (установка файла как устройства подкачки),
- **write** (запись данных в файл),
- **lock** (заблокировать файл), create (создать новый файл),
- **rename** (переименовать файл),
- **mounton** (монтировать файл как файловую систему),
- **quotaon** (включить дисковые квоты),
- **relabelfrom** (изменить метку безопасности файла с более низким уровнем конфиденциальности) и
- **link** (создать жесткую ссылку на файл).

**allow bash_exec secret_exec:process { ... }**: это правило предоставляет различные разрешения, связанные с процессом, контексту процесса **bash_exec** при взаимодействии с процессами, помеченными как **secret_exec**.

Эти разрешения включают:

- sigchld (получение уведомления об изменении состояния дочернего процесса),
- sigkill (отправка сигнала для завершения процесса),
- sigstop (отправка сигнала для остановки процесса),
- signull (отправка нулевого сигнала),
- signal (отправка сигнала для процесс),
- ptrace (трассировка или отладка процесса),
- getsched (получение информации о планировании процесса),
- setsched (установка информации о планировании процесса),
- getsession (получение идентификатора сеанса процесса),
- getpgid (получение идентификатора группы процессов),
- setpgid (установка группы процессов ID),
- getcap (получить возможности процесса),
- setcap (установить возможности процесса),
- getattr (получить атрибуты процесса),
- setrlimit (установить ограничения ресурсов для процесса).

**neverallow bash_exec secret_exec:process transition:** это правило запрещает любой переход процесса из контекста **bash_exec** в контекст **secret_exec**, гарантируя, что процессы с контекстом **bash_exec** не смогут перейти на более высокие уровни конфиденциальности.

Основываясь на этих правилах и данных контекстах файлов, вот что процесс с контекстом **bash_exec** сможет сделать с каждым из трех исполняемых файлов в **/opt**:

**/opt/confidential_exec (контекст: u:r:secret_exec:s0:c0):**

**/opt/secret_exec (контекст: u:r:secret_exec:s1:c0):**

**/opt/topsecret_exec (контекст: u:r:secret_exec:s2:c0):**

- Прочитать файл
- Записать в файл
- Выполнить файл
- Измените метку безопасности на более высокий уровень
- Удалить файл (отвязать)
- Изменить метку безопасности файла с более низкого уровня (relabelfrom)

Что касается процессов, связанных с этими файлами. Процесс с контекстом bash_exec будет иметь разрешения, перечисленные в правиле
**allow bash_exec secret_exec:process { ... }**. Эти разрешения включают взаимодействие с процессом, отправку сигналов, отслеживание или отладку, а также управление атрибутами, связанными с процессом, и ограничениями ресурсов.

Важно отметить, что политика MLS предназначена для обеспечения строгого контроля доступа на основе уровней конфиденциальности и предотвращения утечки информации с более высоких уровней конфиденциальности на более низкие (без записи, без чтения).